# Typo3 CMS 8.7 - How to use fluid and gridelements togehter?

Tags: typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to render gridelements in typoscript and in HTML. But nothing seems to work.
What I have already tried:
1. Created a CE Backend Layout with two columns:
[image: Overview Column and Code]
2. Added the created layout to page content
[image]
3. Trying to address it in typoscript:

#### First try:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  3597 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  3597 {
    columns {
      10 < .default
      10.wrap = <div class="col1">|</div>
      20 < .default
      20.wrap = <div class="col2">|</div>
    }
    wrap = <div class="element2cols">|</div>
  }
}
```

#### Second Try:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  3597 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  3597 {
    cObject = FILE
    cObject {
      file = fileadmin/config/newdesign/Resources/Private/Templates/Template.html
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column small-6">
    <f:format.raw>
      {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_10}
    </f:format.raw>
  </div>
  <div class="column small-6">
    <f:format.raw>
      {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_20}
    </f:format.raw>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got my examples from following guides:

1. Followed step by step in this german guide: [jweiland.net](https://jweiland.net/typo3/showcase/gridelements.html#c1268)
2. Followed step by step in this german guide: [marmelade.de](https://www.marmalade.de/magazin/2013/09/typo3-fluid-und-grid-elements-gemeinsam-verwenden/)

Anybody an idea, how to access it in a template in html?
Thanks guys for helping.